# $.ajax working with Firefox, not IE

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code to allow users to login using a lightbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and immediately start downloading files, without being redirected or having the page reloaded. It's perfectly working in Firefox but Internet Explorer keeps showing the login box until I reload the page :(

```
<? if (!$this->session->userdata('user_logged_in')): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="/link/"]').click(function(event){
        var status = $.ajax({
            url: "/status",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        if (status != 'USER_LOGGED_IN')
        {
            $.fn.colorbox({href:"/login"});
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<? endif ?>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) retrieves data using GET requests, which are being cached by IE. You can fix this by telling the browser to not cache AJAX results:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/status",
        async: false,
        cache: false
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `status` is checked before it was set by the $.ajax part, it will keep sending you to the login screen. Try checking the status *after* it was successfully retrieved, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/status',
  async: false,
  success: function(status) {
    if (status != 'USER_LOGGED_IN') {
      // etc
    }
  }
});
```